# Custom StreamsBuilderFactoryBeanConfigurer won't be picked up

Tags: spring-kafka, spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka

I've written the following configurer bean and expected to be executed, but the bean doesn't seem to be executed as execution in debugging mode doesn't even stop when I set a breakpoint inside:

```kotlin
@Bean
fun myStreamsBuilderFactoryBeanConfigurer() =
    StreamsBuilderFactoryBeanConfigurer { factoryBean ->
        factoryBean.setKafkaStreamsCustomizer { }
        factoryBean.streamsConfiguration
    }
```

Using Spring Cloud 2021.0.5 with Kafka Streams.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what is going on. Here is a [StreamsBuilderFactoryBeanConfigurer](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream/blob/3.2.x/binders/kafka-binder/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka-streams/src/test/java/org/springframework/cloud/stream/binder/kafka/streams/function/KafkaStreamsBinderWordCountFunctionTests.java#L411) that we use in a test. [This test](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream/blob/3.2.x/binders/kafka-binder/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka-streams/src/test/java/org/springframework/cloud/stream/binder/kafka/streams/function/KafkaStreamsBinderWordCountFunctionTests.java#L104) should fail if the configurer is not working. Please take a look at this [assertion](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream/blob/3.2.x/binders/kafka-binder/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka-streams/src/test/java/org/springframework/cloud/stream/binder/kafka/streams/function/KafkaStreamsBinderWordCountFunctionTests.java#L135).

If things are still failing for you, please create a very minimal Java sample where we can debug this further.